# Labeling a 'plot()' Axis With a Percent Sign Using the 'bquote()' and 'str2lang()' Functions in R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have the following plot.

```
plot(0, xlab = '', ylab = '')
```

For reasons I'm not going to take the time to explain here, I have to use the `bquote()` and `str2lang()` functions to label the horizontal and vertical axes. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
Labels <- c('cm^2~hr^-1', '%')
mtext(bquote(.(str2lang(Labels[1]))), side = 1)
mtext(bquote(.(str2lang(Labels[2]))), side = 2)
```

Why doesn't the `'%'` symbol work here? Is there a workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print a literal percent symbol you have to quote it as `%` is a "special" character in `?plotmath`:

```r
plot(0, xlab = '', ylab = '')

Labels <- c('cm^2~hr^-1', '"%"')
mtext(bquote(.(str2lang(Labels[1]))), side = 1, line = 3)
mtext(bquote(.(str2lang(Labels[2]))), side = 2, line = 3)
```

[image]